# Need a little twitch in my regex to get all the numbers

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How to fix the pattern to get the all listed numbers. Currently what I'm getting with the way I've tried is given below:

```
import re

content='''
(555) 567-4523, 555 567 4523, (555) 567 4523, 555-567-4623
+91-8071805024, +91-11-2352280
'''
print(re.findall(r"\+?.\d+.-?\(?\d+.\)?-?\s?\w*.-?\s?\w*.",content))
```

Result I'm getting:

```
['(555) 567-4523,', ' 555 567 4523, (', ' 567 4523, 555-567-', '+91-8071805024, +91-', '11-2352280']
```

Result I'm after:

```
(555) 567-4523, 555 567 4523, (555) 567 4523, 555-567-4623
+91-8071805024, +91-11-2352280
```

Comment: If you could explain the rules, it would be clearer. Here, take a look at a [slightly "tweaked" pattern of yours](https://regex101.com/r/7r8Ghe/1).

Comment: Cant you simply split on `,` and `\n` - like `[,\n]\s*` (added `\s*` to remove unwanted space). [See it here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aFNWb6/2).

Comment: Thanks everyone for such invaluable comments. Instead of using any webpage i just used the above snippet for your consideration to provide me with any suggestion as to how the regex pattern might be. As i'm very new to learn regex so i expected any better pattern to catch all the phone numbers from the snippet. I never wanted to get those data without using regex. I tried to mimic that i'm fetching those numbers from a real website. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply split the (stripped) string using

```
[,\n]\s*
```

you'll end up with an array of phone numbers.

It matches all commas **or** newlines, and any following whitespace.

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/0xwi94).